# Android: How to make onTouch work like onClick?

Tags: android, dictionary, touch-event

I used this tutorial http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android to display Map view and set onTouch event to display a toast message (latitude/longitude) when I click on a particular area. Now my problem is that the Toast message is displayed the moment I touch the screen even if it is to move the map? I want to display the toast only if the touch down point and touch up point are the same. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the move bit is set in the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE)

```
if(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
```

Comment: But for some reason, it isnt working :( I still get the toast displayed on touch.

Comment: You should print out all events and their flags and then do some testing to see what events are generated based on user input. Then decide on strategy to filter the events.

Comment: Use `(getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)`  to filter out action only. Print this out (or to log). Result means: 0 - down, 1 - up, 2 - move, 3 - canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the correct way to do this? I am pretty sure there is a better way.

```
if (event.getAction() == 0) {                
    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();
}
if(event.getAction() == 1) {
  if(event.getX() == touchX && event.getY()== touchY){
    GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
         p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
         p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, `event.getAction() == 0` is not the right way. `event.getAction()` returns all flags. You should just check for one bit.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, when I press down and drag nothing happens, but if I press down and release it worked! just like onClickListener behavior.

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         // yer Code here ...........
      }

      return false;
  }
```

Comment: It dint work for me :( It fired whenever I released my finger. Even if I did a drag.